# How to download a list of files with the possibility of resuming?

Tags: macos, command-line, download

I have a list of URLs to some files to download. These are actual URLs ending with complete file names in the form of `http://domain.com/foobar.jpg`.

All of those are stored in a file called `urls.txt`.

How can I download them, with a possibility to resume those downloads?

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: Next time, please ask the actual question instead.

Answer (score 5):

wget – available for most Unixes (and if you look hard, Windows):

```
wget -c http://domain.com/foobar.jpg
```

curl – available for [almost any PC OS](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html):

```
curl -C - -O http://domain.com/foobar.jpg

curl -C - --remote-name-all http://domain.com/foo.jpg http://domain.com/bar.jpg
```

To loop over a set of files stored in `urls.txt`:

```
while read line; do wget -c "$line"; done < urls.txt
```

Comment: I have many URLs that're stored in a file `urls.txt`.  How to feed that to `curl`?

Comment: @duperuser as Lamar asked, Operating system? How you get the URLs can depend on OS.

Comment: @duperuser See update in grawity's answer. grawity, hope you don't mind?

Comment: Wouldn't `-i urls.txt` do it?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with `curl`?

Comment: @duperuser: Yes, it's possible to do it with `curl` using almost exactly the same method as in slhck's edit...

Comment: I use this **wget -c -i urls.txt**